# NuGet.Visual Studio - Unable to get IVsPackageInstallerProjectEvents

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, using NuGet.VisualStudio 4.0.0 and I'm trying to attach to IVsPackageInstallerProjectEvents. But I can't get a reference. An exception is thrown instead:

```
Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageInstallerProjectEvents" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.
```

For some reason everything works fine for IVsPackageInstallerEvents. Btw the [Import] does not work. I have to use componentModel.GetService

```
[Import]
private IVsPackageInstallerEvents installerEvents;

[Import(typeof(IVsPackageInstallerProjectEvents))]
public IVsPackageInstallerProjectEvents installerProjectEvents { get; set; }

public ContributionsMonitor(IComponentModel componentModel)
{
    this.installerEvents = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstallerEvents>();
    this.installerEvents.PackageReferenceAdded += InstallerEventsOnPackageReferenceAdded;
    this.installerEvents.PackageReferenceRemoved += InstallerEventPackageReferenceRemoved;

    this.installerProjectEvents = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstallerProjectEvents>();
    this.installerProjectEvents.BatchEnd += InstallerProjectEventsBatchEnd;
}

private static void InstallerProjectEventsBatchEnd(IVsPackageProjectMetadata metadata)    {
    Debug.WriteLine("Added to {0}", metadata.ProjectName);
}

private static void InstallerEventPackageReferenceRemoved(IVsPackageMetadata metadata)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Remove {0} {1} {2}", metadata.Id, metadata.Title, metadata.VersionString);
}

private static void InstallerEventsOnPackageReferenceAdded(IVsPackageMetadata metadata)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Add {0} {1} {2}", metadata.Id, metadata.Title, metadata.VersionString);
}
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Reinstalling the NuGet extension fixed it for me.

Solution copied from https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3042:

1. From tools > extensions and updates > Installed, uninstall NuGet Package Manager
2. Close all instances of visual studio
3. Delete %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
4. Download NuGet 3.4.4 VSIX for 2015 from https://dist.nuget.org/index.html
5. Double click the VSIX you downloaded to install it
6. Run the Visual Studio developer command prompt as Admin, and execute devenv.exe /setup (wait until the process finishes, you may need to check task manager for it)
7. Start Visual Studio 2015 again